# using same form for insert and edit without having unused variables in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

ok guys/girls, i am new to programming and have a question. i created one winform for insert data into sql server..now i want to use that same form to update data..i already did that with constructor overload and chaining, and it is work!
on main form frmEmployees i have two buttons, btnAddEmployee and btnUpdateEmployee, i also have employeeID (i get id from the datagrid) and a bool variable called 'isEditMode =true', now when i click btnUpdateEmployee i am sending EmployeeID, and isEditMode values to overloaded constructor..and frmAddEmployee opens..there i have global private variabables employeeID and bool isEditmode..and then i set their values via overloaded constructor, and that is work, BUT..when i click btnAddEmployee i am not sending employeeID and isEditMode values..and i come up with unused variables when adding employee..

```
private int employeeID;
private bool isEditMode;
public frmAddEmployee()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  this.AutoValidate = AutoValidate.Disable;
    }
public frmAddEmployee(int employeeID, bool isEditMode): this()
{
  this.employeeID = employeeID;
  this.isEditMode = isEditMode;
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you share more code? This is really not enough to understand your issue. At least the parts triggered by your buttons and maybe a screen shot of your app just to visualize easily what you are explaining

Comment: What sql are you using_

Answer (score 1):

You haven't showed us a lot of code but i will give you good example of how i am handing communication between program and SQL Database.

So first of all I create class for each object. In your example i see you have `Employee` so i would create class with few information (variables) about each of my employee and functions i want to have for them. So class would look something like this:

```
public class Employee
{
    static string databaseString = "";
    public int Id { get { return _Id; } } //This is property
    public string Name { get { return _Name; } set { _Name = value; } } //This is property

    private int _Id; //This is private variable used by property
    private string _Name; //This is private variable used by property

    public Employee()
    {
        //Constructor used to create empty object
    }

    public Employee(int Id)
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(databaseString))
            {
                con.Open();
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT NAME FROM Employee WHERE ID = @ID", con))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Id);

                    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    //I am usin IF(dr.Read()) instead of WHILE(dr.Read()) since i want to read only first row.
                    if (dr.Read())
                    {
                        this._Id = Id;
                        this._Name = dr[0].ToString();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("There was no Employee with that ID in database!");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch(SqlException ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    public void Save(bool showMessage)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(databaseString))
        {
            con.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Employee SET NAME = @N WHERE ID = @ID", con))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@N", this._Name);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", this._Id);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                if (showMessage)
                    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Employee saved!");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void Create(string Name, bool showMessage = true)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(databaseString))
        {
            con.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Employee (ID, NAME) VALUES (COALESCE(MAX(ID), 1), @NAME)", con))
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                if (showMessage)
                    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("New Employee created!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now when i have my class i can call it 2 ways:

```
Employee emp = new Employee(); //This will create empty employee object
Employee emp1 = new Employee(1); //This will create employee object and will load employees data from database where employees id == 1
```

Also what i can do is:

```
Employee.Create("SomeName"); //Calling public static method from Employee class. Doesn't require you to create object for static methods
```

or if i have loaded employee and want to change it's name and then save i would do it like this:

```
Employee emp2 = new Employee(1); //Created and loaded emp from database
emp2.Name = "Changed Name";
emp2.Save(); //Called public method.
```

So now if you have form which display one employee it would look like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Employee emp;

    public Form(int EmployeeID)
    {
        InitializeComponents();

        //Creating new object of Employee but with constructor that will automatically load variables into it.
        emp = new Employee(EmployeeID);

        //Checking to see if employee is loaded since if there was no employee with given ID it would return null
        if(emp.Id == null || < 1)
        {
            DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Employee doesn't exist. Do you want to create new one?", "Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
            if(dr == DialogResult.No)
            {
                //User doesn't want to create new employee but since there is no employee loaded we close form
                this.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                Employee.Create("New Employee");
                MessageBox.Show("New employee created");
                //Here we need to load this employee with code like emp = new Employee(newEmployeeId);
                //To get new employee id you have 2 options. First is to create function inside Employee class that will Select MAX(ID) from Employee and return it. (bad solution)
                //Second solution is to return value upon creating new employee so instead function `public static void Create()` you need to have `public static int Create()` so it returns newly created ID of new row in SQL database. I won't explain it since you are new and it will be too much information for now. You will easily improve code later. For now you can use Select Max(id) method
            }
        }

        textBox1.Text = emp.Id;
        textBox2.Text = emp.Name;
    }

    private void OnButton_Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to save changes?", "Save", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
        if(dr == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
             emp.Save();
        }
        else
        {
            //Here create private Reload function inside form that will do emp = Employee(emp.Id) and then set UI again.
        }
    }

    private void OnButton_CreateNewEmployee_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Employee.Create("New Employee");

        int newEmpID = something; //As i said up create method to select MAX ID or update SQL inside Create function to return newly created ID

        //I am using using since after form closes it automatically disposes it
        using(Form1 f = new Form1(newEmpID))
        {
            f.showDialog()
        }
        this.Close();
    }
}
```